# Installing C++ library on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, devil

I must be a noob, always have trouble installing on Linux. I'm trying to install from: http://openil.sourceforge.net/download.php. So I followed the manual (http://openil.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php) using DevIL 1.7.8 tar.gz from the DL page.

1. I see no precompiled .so's as the manual states.
2. It try to compile myself and I see no OpenIL additions to usr/lib or usr/include (as the manual states) after doing a config,build,install.
3. I supposedly installed it through package manager...but I still don't know where the files I need to include/link to are.

UPDATE: A closer look at the install output for 2. above shows that stuff was actually installed under user/local (thanks alot manual).

So just to be certain, how do I go about linking the .so and the .h to my program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for 3:

Here's what I did (Ubuntu 11.04):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdevil1c2 libdevil-dev
$ apt-file show libdevil1c2
libdevil1c2: /usr/bin/ilur
libdevil1c2: /usr/lib/libIL.so.1
libdevil1c2: /usr/lib/libIL.so.1.1.0
libdevil1c2: /usr/lib/libILU.so.1
libdevil1c2: /usr/lib/libILU.so.1.1.0
libdevil1c2: /usr/lib/libILUT.so.1
libdevil1c2: /usr/lib/libILUT.so.1.1.0
libdevil1c2: /usr/share/doc/libdevil1c2/changelog.Debian.gz
libdevil1c2: /usr/share/doc/libdevil1c2/copyright
libdevil1c2: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libdevil1c2
```

Comment: I have the same thing now too. But it appears that only certain functions I need are being #included. I'm afraid this is getting specific to the library, so I'll move this problem to a new question.

Comment: rgbdslam for indigo was looking for libIL.so.1 which led me to this question. `sudo apt-get install libdevil1c2` was just what I needed.